# How to get the value from previous tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 view controllers. In the first I select a categorie in a tableview. In the next view I want to show all the products within that categorie I selected in the previous tableview. I get the data from my database with a php file.

This is my firstViewController.m The 'catVal' is the value I wanna give to my next ViewController.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    KiesProduct *proView = [[KiesProduct alloc] initWithNibName:@"KiesProduct" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:proView animated:YES];
    NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *catVal = [info objectForKey:@"Cat_naam"];
    [productVC fillArrayProducts:catVal];


}
```

In my second view controller I have the function fillArayProducts.

```
-(void) fillArrayProducts:(NSString *)cat{
    NSLog(@"test");
    NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kGETProducts];
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@",@"Pro_cat",cat]];
    [postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];

    NSError *error;

    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    arrayProducts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<[json count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:i];
        [arrayProducts addObject:[info objectForKey:@"Pro_naam"]];
    } 
    NSLog(@"%@",arrayProducts);  

}
```

my secondViewController.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#define kGETProducts @"http://localhost/getProducts.php"
@interface KiesProduct : UITableViewController{
    NSMutableArray *json;
    NSMutableArray *arrayProducts;
    NSURLConnection *postConnection; 
}
-(IBAction)add:(id)sender;
-(void) fillArrayProducts:(NSString *)cat;
@end
```

When i try this '[productVC fillArrayProducts:catVal];' in my tableview DID Select row function it doesn't work. Anybody got an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u are calling ur second view *proView and then you are calling fillArrayProducts on productVC instead. change to

```
KiesProduct *proView = [[KiesProduct alloc] initWithNibName:@"KiesProduct" bundle:nil];
NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *catVal = [info objectForKey:@"Cat_naam"];
[proView fillArrayProducts:catVal];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:proView animated:YES];
```